# How can I access data that changes locations and header names across workbooks?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to access data that changes locations and header names across different workbooks. This is part of a bigger project but this is the only part I cannot figure out. I have attached images to help clarify what I mean. Let's say that I'm trying to access the range that contains the Net Worth/Balance so I can do some calculations with it. How do I do this if the headers change across dozens of workbooks? On top of that the headers aren't always the first rows with any writing on it. Sometimes there is info in the upper rows that are needed for the workbook but not my purpose.

[image]

[image]

The programmer in me wants to use a dictionary and find all variations of the "Net Worth" title that exist but is that the most efficient way? Should I just use a super long if then statement?

Thanks in advance for your help!

****Also if anyone is wondering if I should even use a macro for this please remember this is part of a much larger project where there are many calculations and they are repetitive across workbooks. My only difficulty is finding where the data is in each workbook.

Comment: I've dealt with similar challenges before and have never found any remotely practical or efficient way of dealing with non-standardized worksheets. Too many unpredictable variables (e.g., how many different spellings; do any of the header names exist anywhere in the data where they aren't headers, like, for instance in somebody's name or address; are columns always in the same order, etc., etc.).  I get that you may not have any option in this, but I promise you the best answer is to standardize everything you possibly can. Automation without standardization is a mess. Good luck! (not sarcasm)

Comment: I agree with @SeanW333 in tems of standardization. This processing can not be fully automated. If you already have that messy input, I would combine programming and human intelligence. 1st I would search for a field containing ID in all files and delete the blanks from left and from above, while marking files without an ID field that should be checked/edited manually. Then when all applicable sheets have an ID in A1, then you would need to arrange the columns by identifying them by content as school and class have a limited value lists and a column with only numbers must be Balance. Nice job.